# Code Performance when adding input file date check

Tags: vbscript

The code's run time increases from under 5 minutes to over an hour with the following change:

From:

```
If objFSO.FileExists(inputFile) then
```

To:

```
If FormatDateTime(objFile.DateLastModified,vbShortDate) = FormatDateTime(Date,vbShortDate) Then
```

I have tried leaving the initial check just on if the file exists and moving the input file date check at the bottom of the code.

This has made no improvements to run time

Dim arrName
    Dim arrFields
    Dim strName

```
Dim inputFile : inputFile = "\\dgdgdgd\xyx.csv"
Dim newInputFile : newInputFile = "xyx_NEW.csv"
Dim fileLocation : fileLocation = "....csv"
Dim inputgz: inputgz = "...xyx.csv.gz"
Dim archivegz: archivegz ="...xyx.csv."& Year(date) & Month(date) & 
Day(date)&".gz"
Dim wLine : wLine = ""
Dim numLine : numLine = 0


Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objFile=objFso.GetFile(inputFile)
If FormatDateTime(objFile.DateLastModified,vbShortDate) = 
FormatDateTime(Date,vbShortDate) Then

'No date check
'If objFSO.FileExists(inputFile) then
        objFile.Copy newInputFile
    Set objRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(newInputFile, ForReading)
    Set objWrite = objFSO.CreateTextFile(fileLocation)
else
writeToLog("ERROR: File is not current (" & inputFile & ")")
objFso.DeleteFile(inputFile)
wscript.quit
End If


strLine = objRead.ReadLine
objWrite.WriteLine(strLine)

writeToLog("Read Input file and find records that match XYZ in 14, 17 and 18 fields")

Do Until objRead.AtEndOfStream

strLine = objRead.ReadLine
objWrite.WriteLine(strLine)
Do Until objRead.AtEndOfStream
strLine = objRead.ReadLine
arrFields = Split(strLine, vbTab)
IF instr(arrFields(14),"XYZ") > 0 OR instr(arrFields(17),"XYZ") > 0 OR 
instr(arrFields(18),"XYZ") > 0 THEN
objWrite.WriteLine(strLine)
END IF


Loop

objRead.Close()
objWrite.Close()

Sub writeToLog(theString)
    wscript.echo(Date & " - " & Time & " - " & theString)
End Sub
```

Expected run time ideally should be under 10 minutes.

Comment: Just some additional information. File size is 110mb with 17,000 rows.

Comment: I have tried swapping the drive location. It seem's to now be also running slow with the input file statement as well.

Comment: You need to show all your code, as your changes would make no substantive change in speed unless it's in a loop.

Comment: @Kron What will happen if put the input file on a local drive? I mean will there still be difference in run time?